# uncaught type error cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I was unable to find the solution for my problem (or I just missed it) so I try to get an answer from you.

I have the following html:

```
<input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="69" maxlength="30" onmouseout="CheckFieldLength(title, 'charcount2', 'remaining2', 30);" onkeydown="CheckFieldLength(title, 'charcount2', 'remaining2', 30);" onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(title, 'charcount2', 'remaining2', 30);"/></td>
```

I am trying to get the length of the characters of the input field as the following:

```
<span id="charcount2">0</span> characters entered   | <span id="remaining2">140</span> characters remaining
```

The js file is the following to do the trick:

```
function CheckFieldLength(fn,wn,rn,mc) {
    var len = fn.value.length;
    if (len > mc) {
        fn.value = fn.value.substring(0,mc);
        len = mc;
    }
    document.getElementById(wn).innerHTML = len;
    document.getElementById(rn).innerHTML = mc - len;
}
```

But, I just keep getting the following error:

```
uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that function like this

```
CheckFieldLength(this, 'charcount2', 'remaining2', 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **this** instead of **title**!!

```
<input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="69" maxlength="30" 
    onmouseout="CheckFieldLength(this, 'charcount2', 'remaining2', 30);" 
    onkeydown="CheckFieldLength(this, 'charcount2', 'remaining2', 30);" 
    onkeyup="CheckFieldLength(this, 'charcount2', 'remaining2', 30);"/>
```

'this' keyword will pass the current element as an object to the javascript function and the rest will be taken care of the function you have.